# Copy activity with simultaneous renaming of a file. From blob to blob

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a "copy data" activity in Azure Data Factory. I want to copy .csv files from blob container X to Blob container Y. I don't need to change the content of the files in any way, but I want to add a timestamp to the name, e.g. rename it. However, I get the following error "Binary copy does not support copying from folder to file". Both the source and the sink are set up as binary.

Comment: If you want to copy files in the folder to another container and rename them, you need use get metadata + foreach active +inner active(copy active )  to achieve it.

Comment: Hi @Vompsis, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the files and rename them, you pipeline should like this:

1. **Create a [Get Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) active to get the file list(dataset Binary1)**:
   [image]
2. **Create [For Each active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) to copy the each file**:`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`:
   [image]
3. **Foreach inner active, create a copy active with source dataset
   Binary2(same with Binary2) with dataset parameter to specify the source file**:
   [image]
4. **Copy active sink setting, create the sink Binary3 also with
   parameter to rename the files**:
   `@concat(split(item().name,'.')[0],utcnow(),'.',split(item().name,'.')[1])`:
   [image]
5. **Run the pipeline and check the output:**
   [image]

Note: The example I made just copy the files to the same container but with new name.